# PHP SoapFault: getCode=0 and getMessage= Wrong Version

Tags: php, wsdl

I generated needed classes from WSDL file. When I call web service, it's return code as 0 and message as 'Wrong Version'

```
 try {
        self::setSoapHeaderSendSms(new RequestSOAPHeader(Config::get('USER'), Config::get('PASS'), Config::get('SERVICE_ID')));

        return $this->setResult(self::getSoapClient()->SendSms($_rightelSmsStructSendSms));
    } catch (SoapFault $soapFault) {
        echo $soapFault->getCode() . ": " . $soapFault->getMessage();
    }
```

what's the problem?

This is my request (get from __getLastRequest()):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://rightel.ir/webservices/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:Header><username>myuser</username><password>mypass</password><serviceid>myservice</serviceid><result/><lastError/><internArrayToIterate/><internArrayToIterateIsArray/><internArrayToIterateOffset/></ns1:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:SendSms><ns1:endUserId>userid</ns1:endUserId><ns1:senderCode>mysendercode</ns1:senderCode><ns1:message>Test</ns1:message></ns1:SendSms></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I was set SOAP_1_1 or SOAP_1_2 in WSDL contructor but nothing was changed!